# If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line

Tags: php, email, smtp

When I do a test email for a contact form in Live Server and press 'Send' nothing happens, no email goes through and no success message. Am I missing something in my PHP code or do I need to setup SMTP?

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

// If you intend you use SMTP, uncomment next line
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';


// Set the recipient email address here
$recipients = array();

$recipients[] = array(
    'email' => 'contact@westonborst.com',
    'name' => 'Weston'
);


// Set the sender email address here
$sender = array(
    'email' => 'contact@westonborst.com',
    'name' => 'Weston'
);


// reCaptcha Secret Key - Add this only if you use reCaptcha with your Contact Forms
$recaptcha_secret = '';


// PHPMailer Initialization
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line


// End of SMTP


// Form Messages
$message = array(
    'success'           => 'Thank you for your message. It has been sent.',
    'error'             => 'There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.',
    'error_bot'         => 'Bot Detected! Message could not be send. Please try again.',
    'error_unexpected'  => 'There was an unexpected error trying to send your message. Please try again later.',
    'recaptcha_invalid' => 'Captcha not Validated! Please Try Again.',
    'recaptcha_error'   => 'Captcha not Submitted! Please Try Again.'
);

// Form Processor
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

    $prefix    = !empty( $_POST['prefix'] ) ? $_POST['prefix'] : '';
    $submits   = $_POST;
    $botpassed = false;
    
    $message_form                 = !empty( $submits['message'] ) ? $submits['message'] : array();
    $message['success']           = !empty( $message_form['success'] ) ? $message_form['success'] : $message['success'];
    $message['error']             = !empty( $message_form['error'] ) ? $message_form['error'] : $message['error'];
    $message['error_bot']         = !empty( $message_form['error_bot'] ) ? $message_form['error_bot'] : $message['error_bot'];
    $message['error_unexpected']  = !empty( $message_form['error_unexpected'] ) ? $message_form['error_unexpected'] : $message['error_unexpected'];
    $message['recaptcha_invalid'] = !empty( $message_form['recaptcha_invalid'] ) ? $message_form['recaptcha_invalid'] : $message['recaptcha_invalid'];
    $message['recaptcha_error']   = !empty( $message_form['recaptcha_error'] ) ? $message_form['recaptcha_error'] : $message['recaptcha_error'];


    // Bot Protection
    if( isset( $submits[ $prefix . 'botcheck' ] ) ) {
        $botpassed = true;
    }

    if( !empty( $submits[ $prefix . 'botcheck' ] ) ) {
        $botpassed = false;
    }

    if( $botpassed == false ) {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['error_bot'] . '" }';
        exit;
    }


    // reCaptcha
    if( isset( $submits['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {

        $recaptcha_data = array(
            'secret' => $recaptcha_secret,
            'response' => $submits['g-recaptcha-response']
        );

        $rc_verify = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" );
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $recaptcha_data ) );
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        $rc_response = curl_exec( $rc_verify );

        $g_response = json_decode( $rc_response );

        if ( $g_response->success !== true ) {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['recaptcha_invalid'] . '" }';
            exit;
        }
    }

    $html_title = !empty( $submits['html_title'] ) ? $submits['html_title'] : 'Form Response';
    $forcerecaptcha = ( !empty( $submits['force_recaptcha'] ) && $submits['force_recaptcha'] != 'false' ) ? true : false;
    $replyto = !empty( $submits['replyto'] ) ? explode( ',', $submits['replyto'] ) : false;

    if( $forcerecaptcha ) {
        if( !isset( $submits['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['recaptcha_error'] . '" }';
            exit;
        }
    }

    $mail->Subject = !empty( $submits['subject'] ) ? $submits['subject'] : 'Form response from your website';
    $mail->SetFrom( $sender['email'] , $sender['name'] );

    if( !empty( $replyto ) ) {
        if( count( $replyto ) > 1 ) {
            $replyto_e = $submits[ $replyto[0] ];
            $replyto_n = $submits[ $replyto[1] ];
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $replyto_e , $replyto_n );
        } elseif( count( $replyto ) == 1 ) {
            $replyto_e = $submits[ $replyto[0] ];
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $replyto_e );
        }
    }

    foreach( $recipients as $recipient ) {
        $mail->AddAddress( $recipient['email'] , $recipient['name'] );
    }

    $unsets = array( 'prefix', 'subject', 'replyto', 'message', $prefix . 'botcheck', 'g-recaptcha-response', 'force_recaptcha', $prefix . 'submit' );

    foreach( $unsets as $unset ) {
        unset( $submits[ $unset ] );
    }

    $fields = array();

    foreach( $submits as $name => $value ) {
        if( empty( $value ) ) continue;

        $name = str_replace( $prefix , '', $name );
        $name = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $name ) );

        if( is_array( $value ) ) {
            $value = implode( ', ', $value );
        }

        $fields[$name] = $value;
    }

    $response = array();

    foreach( $fields as $fieldname => $fieldvalue ) {
        $response[] = $fieldname . ': ' . $fieldvalue;
    }

    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

    $body = implode( "<br>", $response ) . $referrer;

    $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
    $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

    if( $sendEmail == true ):
        if( $autores && !empty( $replyto_e ) ) {
            $send_arEmail = $autoresponder->Send();
        }

        echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message['success'] . '" }';
    else:
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['error'] . '<br><br><strong>Reason:</strong><br>' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
    endif;

} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['error_unexpected'] . '" }';
}

?>
```

---

Not sure why it won't send, here is what I tried? Any advise? (And I removed my password from the code)

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

// If you intend you use SMTP, uncomment next line
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';


// Set the recipient email address here
$recipients = array();

$recipients[] = array(
    'email' => 'borstweston@gmail.com',
    'name' => 'Weston'
);


// Set the sender email address here
$sender = array(
    'email' => 'borstweston@gmail.com',
    'name' => 'Weston'
);


// reCaptcha Secret Key - Add this only if you use reCaptcha with your Contact Forms
$recaptcha_secret = '';


// PHPMailer Initialization
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com.";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "borstweston@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->SetFrom("borstweston@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "";
$mail->Body ="";
$mail->AddAddress($sendTo);



// End of SMTP


// Form Messages
$message = array(
    'success'           => 'Thank you for your message. It has been sent.',
    'error'             => 'There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.',
    'error_bot'         => 'Bot Detected! Message could not be send. Please try again.',
    'error_unexpected'  => 'There was an unexpected error trying to send your message. Please try again later.',
    'recaptcha_invalid' => 'Captcha not Validated! Please Try Again.',
    'recaptcha_error'   => 'Captcha not Submitted! Please Try Again.'
);

// Form Processor
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

    $prefix    = !empty( $_POST['prefix'] ) ? $_POST['prefix'] : '';
    $submits   = $_POST;
    $botpassed = false;
    
    $message_form                 = !empty( $submits['message'] ) ? $submits['message'] : array();
    $message['success']           = !empty( $message_form['success'] ) ? $message_form['success'] : $message['success'];
    $message['error']             = !empty( $message_form['error'] ) ? $message_form['error'] : $message['error'];
    $message['error_bot']         = !empty( $message_form['error_bot'] ) ? $message_form['error_bot'] : $message['error_bot'];
    $message['error_unexpected']  = !empty( $message_form['error_unexpected'] ) ? $message_form['error_unexpected'] : $message['error_unexpected'];
    $message['recaptcha_invalid'] = !empty( $message_form['recaptcha_invalid'] ) ? $message_form['recaptcha_invalid'] : $message['recaptcha_invalid'];
    $message['recaptcha_error']   = !empty( $message_form['recaptcha_error'] ) ? $message_form['recaptcha_error'] : $message['recaptcha_error'];


    // Bot Protection
    if( isset( $submits[ $prefix . 'botcheck' ] ) ) {
        $botpassed = true;
    }

    if( !empty( $submits[ $prefix . 'botcheck' ] ) ) {
        $botpassed = false;
    }

    if( $botpassed == false ) {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['error_bot'] . '" }';
        exit;
    }


    // reCaptcha
    if( isset( $submits['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {

        $recaptcha_data = array(
            'secret' => $recaptcha_secret,
            'response' => $submits['g-recaptcha-response']
        );

        $rc_verify = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" );
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $recaptcha_data ) );
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $rc_verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        $rc_response = curl_exec( $rc_verify );

        $g_response = json_decode( $rc_response );

        if ( $g_response->success !== true ) {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['recaptcha_invalid'] . '" }';
            exit;
        }
    }

    $html_title = !empty( $submits['html_title'] ) ? $submits['html_title'] : 'Form Response';
    $forcerecaptcha = ( !empty( $submits['force_recaptcha'] ) && $submits['force_recaptcha'] != 'false' ) ? true : false;
    $replyto = !empty( $submits['replyto'] ) ? explode( ',', $submits['replyto'] ) : false;

    if( $forcerecaptcha ) {
        if( !isset( $submits['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['recaptcha_error'] . '" }';
            exit;
        }
    }

    $mail->Subject = !empty( $submits['subject'] ) ? $submits['subject'] : 'Form response from your website';
    $mail->SetFrom( $sender['email'] , $sender['name'] );

    if( !empty( $replyto ) ) {
        if( count( $replyto ) > 1 ) {
            $replyto_e = $submits[ $replyto[0] ];
            $replyto_n = $submits[ $replyto[1] ];
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $replyto_e , $replyto_n );
        } elseif( count( $replyto ) == 1 ) {
            $replyto_e = $submits[ $replyto[0] ];
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $replyto_e );
        }
    }

    foreach( $recipients as $recipient ) {
        $mail->AddAddress( $recipient['email'] , $recipient['name'] );
    }

    $unsets = array( 'prefix', 'subject', 'replyto', 'message', $prefix . 'botcheck', 'g-recaptcha-response', 'force_recaptcha', $prefix . 'submit' );

    foreach( $unsets as $unset ) {
        unset( $submits[ $unset ] );
    }

    $fields = array();

    foreach( $submits as $name => $value ) {
        if( empty( $value ) ) continue;

        $name = str_replace( $prefix , '', $name );
        $name = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $name ) );

        if( is_array( $value ) ) {
            $value = implode( ', ', $value );
        }

        $fields[$name] = $value;
    }

    $response = array();

    foreach( $fields as $fieldname => $fieldvalue ) {
        $response[] = $fieldname . ': ' . $fieldvalue;
    }

    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

    $body = implode( "<br>", $response ) . $referrer;

    $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
    $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

    if( $sendEmail == true ):
        if( $autores && !empty( $replyto_e ) ) {
            $send_arEmail = $autoresponder->Send();
        }

        echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message['success'] . '" }';
    else:
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['error'] . '<br><br><strong>Reason:</strong><br>' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
    endif;

} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "' . $message['error_unexpected'] . '" }';
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you have a problem with code you wrote its always a good idea to strip it back to the minimal necessary to replicate the issue (actually its better to build up your code in increments of functionality, testing each new thing as you go along). If you get stuck then then post JUST THE CODE required to recreate the issue (there's FAQ about this somwhere)

Answer (score 0):

If you fill everything correctly this should work. (I have tried it)

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();


try {
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "Your Email Address";
    $mail->Password = "Your Password";
    $mail->SetFrom("From Name");
    $mail->Subject = "Message Subject";
    $mail->Body ="Message Body ";
    $mail->AddAddress('Sent email to this address');

    if($mail->Send()) {
        // e-posta başarılı ile gönderildi
      echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'error : '.$e;
}
```

if not please share the error message you are getting.

Comment: Where you put $mail -> Host = "smt.yandex.com", do i replace this with a gmail account? And for Username and Password do I enter my gmail logins or no? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, You need to enter your username and password for gmail and change the host to "smtp.gmail.com".

Comment: I pasted the code I tried below, anything I'm missing? Thanks for the help!!